# User input string and print in Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, user-input

Required to get the user to input a string though it does not need to prompt the user in any for just expects for them to to type it in.

Here's what I have so far:

```
                    mov ah, 3fh     ;3fh Reads the string and moves it to ah
                    int 21H         ;Calls MS-DOS to input string
                    mov ah,9    ;Store interrupt code in ah to display string stored in dx
                    int 21h         ;interrupt code
```

This is the output
[first line user entered hello, second line it repeats what user entered, then random symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z4Gu.png)

Not sure why there is all of those symbols after it

Require for a school work sheet, though I don't really understand what I am doing.

Comment: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html

Answer (score 1):

Random symbols are printed because [int 21, 9](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-9.html) prints strings up to `$`.

So you need to add `$` to `[DS:DX + AX]`, where the inputed string ends.
(Why it is `[DS:DX + AX]`? Because [int 21, 3F](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-3f.html) returns number of bytes to `AX`)